# I need to customize the appearance of an uinavigationcontroller (move down the navigation bar) -STORYBOARD iOS5

Tags: xcode, ios5, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, xib

I am creating an iPAD application for iOS5, which has a root tabbar, and every viewcontroller of the tabbar needs to be a navigation controller.

I am having troubles trying to figure out how to  customize the appearance of the uinavigationcontroller so the navigationbar goes 28 pixels down from the statusbar; in that upper banner space, I need to locate a logo (imageview) and a search bar that will be present on every view of the app). My problem is that I dont know if I should:
A) customize the navigation controller 
or 
B) I should create the view on IB as a xib and the integrate it on the Storyboard.
C) should I create categories to modify the standard appearance (position) of the navigation bar.

For option A, I think that it is not possible to subclass the uinavigationcontroller on iOS5 (however I am not entirely sure about that).
For option B, I am worry that if create the xib for the UI, I would need to create all the logic related to the navigation.

I would really appreciate any help or any link that you might consider helpful.

Thanks!.

Answer (score 0):

I think that will do the trick:

```
[yourNavBar setCenter:CGPointMake(yourNavBar.center.x,yourNavBar.center.y + 28)];
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried your suggestion on the ViewDidLoad of the NavigationViewController but although it compiles appropriately the bar did not change its position. Where  should I use this code?

Comment: I think viewDidLoad should be fine. If you provide some of the code that shows how you create UINavigationBar objects maybe i can help more.